# Show diagonal covariance does not guarantee independence.

Tags: independence, covariance

I was trying to show that if two variables have diagonal covariance, this does not necessarily guarantee their independence. For this, I was using an example where $x \sim U(-1,1)$ and $y=X^{2}$ to show this.

Here is my try:

$$
p\left(y | x\right)=\delta\left(y-x^{2}\right)
$$

Now we would like to show that although the two variables are dependent, the covariance matrix between them is diagonal.
$$
\operatorname{cov}[X, Y]=\mathrm{E}[X Y]-\mathrm{E}[X] \mathrm{E}[Y]
$$

$$
p\left(x, y\right)=p\left(x\right) p\left(y | x\right)
$$

\begin{align*}
    E[X Y]=& \iint x y p(x, y) d y d x \\
    &= \iint x y p\left(x\right) p\left(y | x\right) d y d x \\
    &= \int x p\left(x\right) \int y  \delta\left(y-x^{2}\right) d y d x \\
    % &= \int y p(y) d y \cdot \int x p(x) d x \\
    % &= E[X] E[Y] 
\end{align*}
Here is the deal: I was trying to show that all off-diagonal elements are in fact zero, but I'm stuck at that integral. Any suggestion on how to proceed? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(XY)=E(X^3)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1x^3dx=0$.  Therefore the covariance $=0$, since $E(X)=0$.

Comment: What about the probability term then? Also, we are explicitly asked to use $p(x, y)=p(x) p(y | x)$

Comment: Your definition of $p(y|x)$ is unfamiliar to me.  Therefore I just went back to basics.

Comment: @Blade Your integral looks straightforward.  $\int y\delta (y-x^2)dy=x^2$, so your final integral is $\int x^3p(x)dx$, which is identical to that I wrote.